# Why isn't the calculator I'm coding with C working?

Tags: c, while-loop, calculator

I am pretty new to C, and am working on a pretty big project. I am trying to make a calculator, and so far I only have the addition. They way it works is that it asks for how many numbers they want in the addition statement, and then I use a while() loop to try to get all the info. Just some side info - I am using the Cygwin terminal on a Windows 10 operating system.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char Etype;
        printf("Hello! Welcome to your virtual calculator!\n");

        printf("Press 'a' for addition!\n");
        scanf("%c", &Etype);

        if(Etype == 'a' || Etype == 'A') {
                int Anum;
                int x = 1;
                int y;

                printf("How many numbers do you want in this addition statement?\n");
                scanf("%f", &Anum);

                while(x < Anum) {
                        printf("Emter number %d\n", x);
                        scanf("%d", &y);
                        x = x + 1;
                }
        }

}
```

whenever I answer how many numbers I want on my statement, nothing happens. I hope you can help, and if so thank you!

Comment: Your compiler doesn't tell you about at least one major issue? Turn on warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) and recompile.

Comment: What type of value is the `%f` format supposed to read? What is the type of `Anum`?

Comment: Thanks! I am so bad at coding lol (o-o)

Comment: Shawn I don't have -Wall -Wextra working on my compiler

Comment: Which compiler do you use?  Have you found out how to make it give you warnings (or, better, how to make it give you errors) for routine bugs?  If not, spend time now finding out how to crank up the warnings so that you do get told about errors in your code.  Then heed the warnings — the compiler knows more about C than you do.  Of you can't get your current compiler to warn, switch to a better compiler.

Comment: Consider compiling with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Take inspiration from existing open source code on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/). If so permitted consider installing [Debian](https://debian.org) on your computer, and using [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)

Comment: Notice that [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) provides an example of calculator. You do need to read its documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least, you should either look at the compiler warnings, or get a better compiler and look at the compiler warnings.

```
clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
main.c:16:29: warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type
      'int *' [-Wformat]
                scanf("%f", &Anum);
                       ~~   ^~~~~
                       %d
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: Mabey it has something to do with the fact that I'm using vim?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just forget to summary the answer.

To input an integer, you should use `%d` instead of `%f`.

What's more, `x` should be initialized with `0`.

You can edit your codes as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char Etype;
        printf("Hello! Welcome to your virtual calculator!\n");

        printf("Press 'a' for addition!\n");
        scanf("%c", &Etype);

        if(Etype == 'a' || Etype == 'A') {
                int Anum;
                int x = 0; // count from 0
                int y;
                int sum = 0; // to summary the answer

                printf("How many numbers do you want in this addition statement?\n");
                scanf("%d", &Anum); // use %d to input integer

                while(x < Anum) {
                        printf("Emter number %d\n", x);
                        scanf("%d", &y);
                        sum += y; // summary
                        x = x + 1; 
                }
                printf("Answer: %d\n", sum); // print the answer after calculation
        }

}
```

Or a clearer version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char eType[2];

        printf("Hello! Welcome to your virtual calculator!\n");
        printf("Press 'a' for addition!\n");

        scanf("%s", eType);

        if(eType[0] == 'a' || eType[0] == 'A') 
        {
                int n, sum = 0;

                printf("How many numbers do you want in this addition statement?\n");
                scanf("%d", &n);

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                        int x;

                        printf("Enter number %d\n", i);
                        scanf("%d", &x);
                        sum += x;
                }

                printf("Answer: %d\n", sum);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 

i noticed that your code isnt that easy to read
try using varables with easier names like Etype = operation
it makes it user friendly

2.
try adding more operators like - / *

3.
when you declare the variable
and the user enters "add"
you can use a switch statement to to scan only the a like:

```
switch(var){
case'a':
```

it will scan only the a even if the input is "aquaman""aeroplane"
it will still read the a

3.
instead of while use for

> declare an i variable
> make this for statement

```
for(i=0; i>(number of numbers to entered+1);i++ )
printf("number: ");
scanf(...)
```

Comment: *"try using varables with easier names like Etype = operation it makes it user friendly"* Huh? They are already using a variable named `Etype`.

Comment: *"it will scan only the a even if the input is "aquaman""aeroplane" it will still read the a"* You can't even use a string for the switch statement.

Comment: And the whole answer doesn't even address the actual problem.